# The web page is loading before Axios GET responce

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, promise, axios

I am pretty new to Vue.js.

Probably, somebody can help me with the next issue :

The values of my web page's elements have been taken from Axios GET responses that I should send before my page is loaded. But my page is loaded before I got responses from the server. And I get an error that values are undefined.

My main.vue file

```
  beforeMount()
   {
      this.firstTimeRun();
   },
```

My mixin.js  file

```
   methods: {
    async firstTimeRun() {
        await this.getConfig();
        await this.getAlarmStatus();
    },
    async getConfig() {
        const configResponce = await axios.get('http://10.10.10.10/multi_get.json?c0=config')
            .then((res => { this.config = res; }))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        this.$store.commit("setConfigData", this.config);
    },
    async getAlarmStatus() {
        const alarmResponce = await axios.get('http://10.10.10.10/multi_get.json?c0=alarm_status')
            .then((res => {
                this.alarm_status = res;
            }))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        this.$store.commit("setAlarmData", this.alarm_status);
    },

   // In this method I fill the elements and I suppose to use data from getConfig() and 
   getAlarmStatus() methods.

   fillElements(){
    // Do something...
    }
  }
```

Does anybody have an answer for it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

when you call your get method add e.preventDefault method. It will stop page loading when doing clicking on submit button.

```
async getConfig(e) {

e.preventDefault();
        const configResponce = await axios.get('http://10.10.10.10/multi_get.json?c0=config')
            .then((res => { this.config = res; }))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        this.$store.commit("setConfigData", this.config);
    },
```